# Undefined parameters [kinematics_file] while creating urdf

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic, xacro, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial on how to create a new URDF from an UR5 robot and a custom gripper.

https://gramaziokohler.github.io/compas_fab/latest/examples/03_backends_ros/07_ros_create_urdf_ur5_with_measurement_tool.html

but when i try to create the urdf using this command:

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder -o ur5_with_measurement_tool.urdf ur5_with_measurement_tool.xacro
```

i get this message:

```
Undefined parameters [kinematics_file]
```

i see that this parameter is new in the repo that i'm using....

https://github.com/fmauch/universal_robot

my question is... is it obligatory to have this repo in order to work with ur-robot-driver?
or should i move to the original universal-robot package and try it again?

Thank you in advance.

ROS Version: melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344870/undefined-parameters-%5Bkinematics_file%5D-while-creating-urdf/) by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is it obligatory to have this repo in order to work with ur-robot-driver?

No, it isn't.

If you don't use it though, you'll end up with the default URDF, which means the kinematic calibration of *your* robot will not be taken into account with FK/IK queries.

> i see that this parameter is new in the repo that i'm using....

exactly.

So in order for this to work, you should/could provide that parameter and then you'd be able to follow the tutorial you linked.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on 2020-02-25**:
Thank you for your answer, i moved to the original universal-robot package, and created a new URDF without any problem, but i'm facing a new issue..

When i try to see the urdf in rviz

```
$roslaunch ur5_with_measurement_tool display.launch
```

I get this error

```
$Could not find the GUI, install the 'joint_state_publisher_gui' package
```

Which package would provide me this?

I installed ros melodic from apt

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-25**:
Please don't post follow-up questions in comments under already answered questions.

They have very little visibility. Post a new question.

**Comment by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on 2020-02-25**:
 sorry, i'm new in the forum, i will open a new question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-25**:
No problem. No need to apologise.